# Edit webpack entry field after create-react-app eject

Tags: typescript, webpack, create-react-app

I would like to add a new file to the webpack.config file after ejecting from the create-react-app, but I had no luck so far.

I am trying to add

```
 background: path.join(__dirname, "src/background/index.ts"),
```

to (webpack.config, without comments):

```
entry: [
  isEnvDevelopment &&
    require.resolve('react-dev-utils/webpackHotDevClient'),
  paths.appIndexJs,
].filter(Boolean),
```

I have tried adding it the following way:

```
const background: path.join(__dirname, "src/background/index.ts"),

entry: [
  isEnvDevelopment &&
    require.resolve('react-dev-utils/webpackHotDevClient'),
  paths.appIndexJs,
  background
].filter(Boolean),
```

But this way it is added to the main bundle. I would like to have it separately.

What could I do? Thanks!